# Анимация на JavaFX

Tags: javafx, анимация

Задача такова: есть GridPane, заполненная Label с номерами ячеек. Нужно в заданном порядке изменить цвет фона каждой метки с небольшой задержкой.

Если делать замену цвета в цикле, то обновление интерфейса в момент изменения свойства метки не происходит. Элементы GUI обновляются все сразу, уже при выходе из цикла. Натолкните на мысль, пожалуйста. Ибо с анимацией раньше дела не имел, а задание горит :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)

Простой пример:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                Label label = new Label(String.format("%d-%d", i, j));
                label.setMinSize(30, 30);
                gridPane.add(label, i, j);
            }
        }

        stage.setScene(new Scene(gridPane, 300, 300));
        stage.show();

        new Thread(new Painter(gridPane.getChildren())).start();
    }

    class Painter extends Task<Void> {

        private final List<Node> childrens;

        public Painter(List<Node> childrens) {
            this.childrens = childrens;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            Random random = new Random();
            for(Node node: childrens) {
                Color color = Color.color(random.nextDouble(), random.nextDouble(), random.nextDouble());
                ((Region)node).setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(color, null, null)));
                Thread.sleep(200);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Немного изменил код под свою задачу, работает.
Премного благодарен :)
Результат: http://g.recordit.co/decDz0tMX6.gif

Comment: Приятно видеть благодарность и результат помощи, но правила форума гласят: [Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), [Как публиковать ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)